# Python script runs twice in Autodesk Maya when sent with execfile

Tags: python, maya, execfile

I need to send a script to Maya from an external software written in Maya. I tried to do this with a small example:

```
import socket
import time
from os.path import abspath

ADDR=('127.0.0.1',666)


def execute_file(fileFullPath):
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect(ADDR)
    command = "execfile('%s')" % (fileFullPath)
    client.send(command)
    data = client.recv(1024)
    print data
    client.close()
    time.sleep(.1)
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    py_file = 'hello_world.py'
    py_file = abspath(py_file)
    execute_file(py_file)
```

In hello_world.py I have:

```
print 'hello world'
```

Hovewer, when I execute this, 'hello world' is printed twice in Maya.

Another thing I tried is:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'hello world'
```

But then it doesn't execute at all.

Finally, I have also tried with putting the print in a method and the calling it like this:

```
command = "execfile('%s')" % (fileFullPath)
client.send(command)
data = client.recv(1024)
client.send("exec('start()')")
```

But then I get an *name 'start' is not defined* error

Does someone know why this happens, or has at least an idea on how I could avoid this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the same results in a couple of more predictable ways.

Maya already provides a TCP-based [[command **port**]](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/commandPort.html), which will execute commands coming in over the network; you don't need to write your own server.  You could also use a more robust remote solution like  [[**RPYC**]](https://rpyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [[**ZeroMQ**]](http://zeromq.org/).

Were you running the server at `( '127.0.0.1', 666 )` ***inside*** your Maya? That would explain the duplicate printouts.

Related: is [an **example**](http://theodox.github.io/tag/standalone.html) of how to set up a simple server inside of Maya to respond to commands coming **over HTTP**.

You generally don't want to use **`execfile()`**, if this code will be visible to anybody other than yourself: it's the **biggest security hole** imaginable!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks great. Now I am home with a flu, but as soon I can I will have a closer look and see if what you propose works for me. Anyway, i will let you (+the community) know.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!

As suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485059/sending-multiline-commands-to-maya-through-python-socket) answer, I just had to add *import maya.cmds as mc\n* to the command to execute:

```
command = "import maya.cmds as mc\n import maya.cmds as mc\nexecfile('%s')" % (fileFullPath)
```

Now I would love to know why this piece of code prevents Maya of executing the script twice.